# Split button showing different in chrome and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following split button, made out of

http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/B8PQg/

However, although it looks ok in chrome, in firefox (10) the button part appears slightly misplaced. If I convert the  to  it looks ok, but that's not what I want. Any clues?

Comment: I gave it a shot, and as near as I can figure the stylesheet uses the `line-height` attribute to control the height of the elements. On Chrome this works on the `input` element, not so in Firefox, where the button ends up being two pixels too low. No idea why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just heard back from the bootstrap guys (https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2134) and it appears that they're still working on this and similar issues. They suggested using a button element (which doesn't suit me, but whatever)

note to future: this is for bootstrap version 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the same issue, but when using Bootstrap in ASP.NET I found that the buttons had a off-colour left hand side, particuarly bad in FF, but less so in Chrome and IE.

If you add `border-left: #0074cc 1px solid;` to the style for `btn-primary` it disappears,    and the `1px` border is small enough not to be noticeable.